# Maven: Import target folder from another module

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gulp

I have two modules: BE and FE (means backend and frontend).
FE modules builds with gulp and results are placed into `target` folder.
BE modules is written on spring boot.
Is there any way to import resources from `target` folder FE's module to BE module and pack into spring boot jar to make it standalone jar?

Comment: If you have a dependency from FE --> BE , i'd suspect a dependency smell, should be the other way around. Or have a common module for shared classes and the like and add it as dependy for both FE and BE. Never refer to some other maven modules target folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory in the classpath called:

- /static
- /public
- /resources
- /META-INF/resources

By default, resources are mapped on /**, but you can tune that with the spring.mvc.static-path-pattern property

Special case for webjar. Any resources with a path in /webjars/** are served from jar files.

More info in the documentation [Static Content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

So you'll need to change where you store your FE file.
Or you can customize your MVC configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/mycustompath", "classpath:/anotherone/")
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see how this answer is related to OPs question?

Comment: Because the FE build is using gulp i supposed that it used a single page framework (so static file). So i provide  information how spring(-boot) handle static file.